# Azure DevOps Java fuction deploy multi stage

Tags: java, azure, devops, pipeline

I'm trying to release a pipeline to deploy an azure function written in Java to QA stage in case the change happens in release branch, or into production slot if the change is done in the master branch. I receive the following error:
##[error]Unhandled: Not found mavenPOMFile: /home/vsts/work/1/s/AzureServerless/pom.xml

I've tried several configuration but I'm not findind the solution.. You can find below the pipeline configuration:

```
# Maven
# Build your Java project and run tests with Apache Maven.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/java
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - release
      - master

stages:
  - stage: Staging
    displayName: 'Deploy to Staging Slot'
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release'))
    jobs:
      - deployment: DeploymentJob
        displayName: 'Deployment Job'
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        environment: 'staging'
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: Maven@2
                  displayName: 'Maven pom.xml'
                  inputs:
                    mavenPomFile: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)/pom.xml'
                # Copy files
                - task: CopyFiles@2
                  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
                  inputs:
                    SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
                    Contents: '**/azure-functions/**'
                    TargetFolder: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
                # Create Archive : zip file
                - task: ArchiveFiles@2
                  displayName: 'Archive $(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/target/azure-functions/AzureServerless-1686925779077'
                  inputs:
                    rootFolderOrFile: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/target/azure-functions/AzureServerless-1686925779077'
                    includeRootFolder: false
                    archiveType: 'zip'
                    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'

                - task: AzureFunctionApp@2
                  inputs:
                    azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
                    appType: 'functionAppLinux'
                    appName: 'serverlesstest'
                    deployToSlotOrASE: true
                    resourceGroupName: 'pilot-rg'
                    slotName: 'qa'
                    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
                    runtimeStack: 'JAVA|8'
                    deploymentMethod: 'auto'
                  displayName: 'Release to Staging Slot'

  - stage: Production
    displayName: 'Deploy to Production Slot'
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
    jobs:
      - deployment: DeploymentJob
        displayName: 'Deployment Job'
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        environment: 'production'
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: Maven@2
                  displayName: 'Maven pom.xml'
                  inputs:
                    mavenPomFile: pom.xml
                # Copy files
                - task: CopyFiles@2
                  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
                  inputs:
                    SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
                    Contents: '**/azure-functions/**'
                    TargetFolder: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
                # Create Archive : zip file
                - task: ArchiveFiles@2
                  displayName: 'Archive $(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/target/azure-functions/AzureServerless-1686925779077'
                  inputs:
                    rootFolderOrFile: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/target/azure-functions/AzureServerless-1686925779077'
                    includeRootFolder: false
                    archiveType: 'zip'
                    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'

                - task: AzureFunctionApp@2
                  inputs:
                    azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
                    appType: 'functionAppLinux'
                    appName: 'serverlesstest'
                    deployToSlotOrASE: true
                    resourceGroupName: 'pilot-rg'
                    slotName: 'production'
                    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
                    runtimeStack: 'JAVA|8'
                    deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you checkout the repository?

Comment: Ok it worked, thanks! Apparently in a multi stage job I have to specify the checkout task. Thanks for the tip!